# Base class undefined - cpp

Tags: visual-c++

Got an assignment to build a server that manages a chess game. I received a client and some of the code for the server. I'm having a problem with compiling the project after I started to add the pieces because for some reason the class Piece that all peices inherit from is undifined in all of the pieces.

I tried playing with the files included in each file and searching the problem online for the past two days but nothing worked for me.

```
#pragma once
#include "Rook.h"

class Piece;

class Board
{
public:
        ...

private:
    ...
};
```

```
#pragme once
#include "Player.h"
#include "Board.h"

class Board;

class Piece
{
public:
        ...
private:
    ...
protected: 
        ...
};
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Piece.h"
class Piece;

class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    ...

private:
        ...
};
```

For this code I get:
...\Project1\Rook.h(7,1): error C2504:  'Piece': base class undefined

Comment: Creating a circular dependency between .h files is an easy mistake and gets hard to diagnose in a hurry.  Using incomplete types to work around the compile errors just makes it worse.  Reason through the hierarchy, the .h file that declares Piece must not #include Board.h.  Consider a single .h file to get started so the compile errors are easier to diagnose, clean it up later.

Comment: @HansPassant problem is that the class Piece needs to include Board.h because it has a variable of type Board.

Comment: C++ demands that you use a Board* or Board& when it doesn't know the type yet.  No #include necessary, it can be an incomplete type.  Also logically consistent, a piece doesn't own its own board.  Do think a bit what should happen when a piece is no longer on the board because it was taken.

Comment: @HansPassant got it thankyou